# Cannot configure Vaadin addons maven repository in Artifactory

Tags: maven, vaadin, artifactory

I'm trying to configure the Vaadin addons repository in Artifactory, but I always get this error message:

[image]

When I change the url to just http://maven.vaadin.com, the connection test succeeds, but the artifacts cannot be resolved. I have other remote repositories configured that work.

Currently I have to resort to downloading and deploying the jar files manually.

Any ideas about what I could be doing wrong here?

**Edit**: Specific addon example (although all have failed for me, so far):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
   <artifactId>loginform</artifactId>
   <version>0.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test is failing since the Vaadin addons Maven repository does not support directory listing (browsing).
When Artifactory send a test request to the root of the repository it gets a 404 status:

```
$ curl -vv http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/
*   Trying 54.86.23.48...
* Connected to maven.vaadin.com (54.86.23.48) port 80 (#0)
> GET /vaadin-addons/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: maven.vaadin.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 12:50:53 GMT
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amz-request-id: 2F7E32DADE9E2C20
< x-amz-id-2: EjRvUE7kv4GOdPE0ry+VsmXvmva4QgBptK/CcnSESZbe2AqotmXpAuM3AuChq2Gd
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
* Connection #0 to host maven.vaadin.com left intact
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>vaadin-addons/</Key><RequestId>2F7E32DADE9E2C20</RequestId><HostId>EjRvUE7kv4GOdPE0ry+VsmXvmva4QgBptK/CcnSESZbe2AqotmXpAuM3AuChq2Gd</HostId></Error>
```

However you can still use Artifactory to proxy this repository. You will be able to download artifacts from it.

Comment: Hm, does that work for you? I only fiddled with this connection test after my artifacts didn't get resolved...

Comment: Tested it on Artifactory 4.0 and it works for me. I noticed that some of the Vaadin artifacts available in other public repos such as jcenter.bintray.com could not be downloaded from the vaadin repo (strange)

Comment: BTW, did you try resolving the missing artifacts directly from the vaadin-addons repository?

Comment: Just did, and that works. I'm running Artifactory 3.6.0, maybe I have to update :/

Comment: Can you provide an example of a failing download?

Comment: Tested the dependency you mentioned with Artifactory 4.0 and it works

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for that. I will look for the problem in my maven proxy or artifactory settings/version then.

Comment: Turns out I forgot to add the Vaadin remote repository to the virtual repository. Sorry about that. That connection test error made it too easy to suspect the fault with vaadin...